# Reuse preinstalled software in Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine

Sometimes installing new software takes a lot of time.

I would like to install software in the VM and reuse this software later in new VMs. There are two ways to do that.

1. create an image after installations as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-capture-image-windows-server/) or
2. use the VHD disk with the OS and preinstalled software (e.g. C:)?

In the first case I would just create a new VM directly from that image, in the second case I would attach the disk after the new VM is created.

Which way is preferable and possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to address your two points below.

1) An image is really about creating a sys prepped [1] version from an existing Azure VM ( that presumably has all the software you need installed).

Once you have captured the image, you can then create additional VM(s) based on it.

You can also go Azure Marketplace or VM Depot [2] and choose from a  set of pre-built images and easily spin VMs based on it. This is the quickest way to get up and running with a VM.

2)

A disk is created from an image when you provision a VM. By default an OS disk will be created. But if your image includes data disks those will also be added to the VM.

To your point, #2 allows you to attach additional data disks (number of disks you can attach depends on the size of the VM you are creating). Note that you can attach an empty or an existing disk.

[1]
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb457073.aspx

[2]
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/virtual-machines/